# How do I return the coordinates of my selected polygon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I'm using `google-maps-react` to render an array with several polygons on a map.

When I click on a polygon, I would like it to return all the coordinates for that selected polygon. Can you tell me how I can do that?

**Here is a picture of how I am rendering my coordinates on the map:**

[image]

I would like something else too, if possible, to add a `hover` event when I hover over each of the polygons. In the same way as this video I found on the internet: https://recordit.co/MciFGBL3b7

Here's my code I put at codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-herschel-25rsl?file=/src/App.js

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you reduced your `data.coordinates` json into `auxCoords`. What you can do is to push it into an array, then use this array to map those paths from auxCoords to a `<Polygon/>`. Here's how I achieved this:

1. Pushing the reduced json data in an array

```
import data from "./data.json";
const dataArray = [];

let auxCoords = {
  auxCoords: data.coordinates.reduce(
    (a, [c]) => a.concat([c.map(([lat, lng]) => ({ lat, lng }))]),
    []
  )
};
dataArray.push(auxCoords.auxCoords[0]);
```

2. Inside the `<Map/>`, you will see that I enclosed the `<Polygon/>` in the `{auxCoords.auxCoords.map((poly, key) => ()}`. This is mapping each polygon path arrays from the auxCoords. In this case, it individually creates a `<Polygon/>` object which you can access the path and properties of each shape. Also, notice the `onClick, onMouseover and onMouseout parameters` inside the `<Polygon/>. Luckily, these events are supported by [`google-maps-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#events-2).

```
 return (
      <div>
        <Map
          className="map"
          google={this.props.google}
          onClick={this.onMapClicked}
          initialCenter={{
            lat: -47.7027099655629,
            lng: -22.26485424139211
          }}
          style={{ height: "100%", position: "relative", width: "100%" }}
          zoom={14}
        >
          {auxCoords.auxCoords.map((poly, key) => (
            <Polygon
              key={key}
              paths={poly}
              strokeColor="#0000FF"
              strokeOpacity={0.8}
              strokeWeight={2}
              fillColor="#0000FF"
              fillOpacity={0.35}
              onClick={this.onPolyClick}
              onMouseover={this.onPolyHover}
              onMouseout={this.onPolyHoverOut}
            />
          ))}
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
```

3. Then here are the functions that I called in the above events. In the onClick, I get the path using the props. In the onPolyHover, I get the path from `polygon` using the method `getPaths` then used `setOptions` to change the fillColor when you hover on an individual polygon. In the onPolyHoverOut, I changed back the fillColor to the original fillColor.

```
onPolyClick = (props,polygon, e) => {
    console.log("onclick:");
    console.log(props.paths);
  };

  onPolyHover = (props, polygon, e) => {
    console.log("onHover:");
    console.log(polygon.getPaths());
    polygon.setOptions({ fillColor: "#ff00ff" });
  };

  onPolyHoverOut = (props, polygon, e) => {
    console.log("onHover:");

    polygon.setOptions({ fillColor: "#0000FF" });
  };
```

See this [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/polygon-from-json-data-mapping-iqlfyk?file=Map.js). *Note: use your API key to make the code work.*