# How to return/get coordinates from my Polygon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I'm using `google-maps-react` to render polygons on a map.

When I click on a polygon, I would like it to return all the coordinates for that selected polygon. Can you tell me if that's is possible?

Here's my code I put in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-tree-ikvq1?file=/src/index.js

**And here's where I plot my map:**

```js
<Map
  google={this.props.google}
  className={"map"}
  zoom={4}
  initialCenter={{ lat: 20.0, lng: -70.0 }}
>
  <Polygon
    onClick={this.handleClick}
    paths={triangleCoords}
    strokeOpacity={0.8}
    strokeWeight={2}
    fillColor={this.fillColors[0]}
    fillOpacity={0.35}
  />
</Map>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sample code looks similar to [the code in this question and is a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541422/how-do-i-return-the-coordinates-of-my-selected-polygon). Please see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66574984/11025839).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is the `getPath` method from the Polygon class https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon

In your sandbox I was able to get the path as an object with the Array of length 4 in there:

```
handleClick = (props, polygon, e) => {
  console.log("polygon: ", polygon.getPath());
  const currentColor =
  polygon.fillColor == this.fillColors[0]
    ? this.fillColors[1]
    : this.fillColors[0];
   polygon.setOptions({ fillColor: currentColor });
```

};

Comment: Hey Stuart, thanks, but that doesn't work, I put `polygon.getPath()` and `polygon.getPath().getArray())` and both return a empty array.

Comment: Hi vbernal. Thats correct. It returns an array that you need to extract from eg for the first element: `polygon.getPath().getArray()[0].lat()`. You could do a foreach on this array and extract the lat and lng

Comment: That's work perfectly, but is there any way to return all the coordinates of that specific polygon? Not just the first element.

Comment: I did `const polygonClicked = polygon.getPath().getArray();` and `const auxPolygon = polygonClicked.map((el) => el.lat());` but no matter where I click on the map, it always returns the same coordinates.